# unity3d - Clamp rotation value

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation, clamp

I have an object that rotates according to mouse position, but I want to clamp it so it doesn't get further or lower than certain value. Here is my code:

```
void LookAt () {

        float distance = transform.position.z - Camera.main.transform.position.z;

        Vector3 position = new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, distance);

        position = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(position);
        position.x = Mathf.Clamp(position.x, -70, 70);
        position.z = Mathf.Clamp(position.z, -70, 70);

        Vector3 target = new Vector3 (position.x, transform.position.y, position.z); // Use current object positin.y
        transform.LookAt(target);
    }
```

But unfortunately it doesn't work, it keeps rotating 360.

Edit:
This is a 3D top-down game, I have a tank and I want to rotate it's upper half. The code I wrote above works perfect for the job, but now I don't know how to limit it so the barrel( the part I'm rotating) always facing upwards where the enemies will come from. 70 or whatever are just random values I was testing, first I want to figure what exactly the proper code is,  then determining the values is the easy part.

Comment: Can you give a bit more context ? Detail what you want to do exactly with a screenshot of the scene and give the extract of code where `void LookAt()` is called.

Comment: LookAt() is being called in Update(), and already stated that i don't need my object to rotate 360,I want to lock it's values. Other than that I can't see how a screenshot would be helpful ?!

Comment: Without a minimum of context, it's difficult to provide you a correct answer. You rarely debug a Unity script without knowing how is the scene. We don't know on which object the script is, where the object and the camera are in the scene, what is show by the camera and what is the exact result you want to have. If a screenshot can provide numbers of these informations, you can describe in written if you want.

Comment: Why do you calculate a distance for the object z coordinate in the screen space instead of using nearClipPlane of the camera?

Comment: Also, you shouldn't use the same variable to represent screen space and world space position. It makes your code harder to read and to debug.

Comment: I don't understand this part : "now I don't know how to limit it so the barrel (the part I'm rotating) always facing upwards where the enemies will come from". In one hand, you said that you want to clamp the rotation of your barrel and in other hand you said that it will always facing the enemies. By the way, does "top-down" mean that the action take place on a X/Z axis plane and the camera watch it from above, following the Y-axis ?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the problem is that you're clamping a position, not a rotation. You're having it look at a certain point, but limiting that point rather than the angle that it will need to rotate to meet it. You'll have to use trigonometry to calculate the angle it wants to point in (more specifically, the atan2 function), clamp *that* value to (-70, 70), and then apply *that* rotation to the object (using euler angles). Do you require further clarification on any of these steps?

Cheers.

P.S. Note that atan2 returns a value in radians, but your range and euler angles use degrees.

Answer (score -1):

You limit your target position by 70 units in world space, which is usually a lot, but depends on your game scale. What I think you wanted to do is to limit mouse position by 70 pixels around the screen center. (Please, provide this remarks in the question itself, so we won't have to guess). However, because you used the same variable both for screen space and world space position of the target, you likely got confused and clamped the position after converting it to world space.

Also, you made the y coordinate of the target to be the same as the object. But this means that the object **would have** to rotate 360 degrees every time the target passed it. I assume that what you wanted to do instead is to assume that the target location is located on camera place.

```
void LookAt () {

        var cursorPosition = new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, camera.main.nearClipPlane);
        cursorPosition.x = Mathf.Clamp(position.x, -70, 70);
        cursorPosition.z = Mathf.Clamp(position.z, -70, 70);
        var targetPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(cursorPosition);
        transform.LookAt(targetPosition);
    }
```

Please, provide details about your reasoning and desired behavior when you ask to find errors in your code.

Comment: This is a 3D top-down game, I have a tank and I want to rotate it's upper half. The code I wrote above works perfect for the job, but now I don't know how to limit it so the barrel( the part I'm rotating) always facing upwards where the enemies will come from. 70 or whatever are just random values I was testing, first I want to figure what exactly the proper code is,  then determining the values is the easy part.

Comment: So, were my assumptions about your intended behaviour true or not? You still have to describe the set up of the game world in more detail.